# Uppercase greek letters in math in italic/slanted format

Tags: greek

I read that in math, capital Greek letters should be italic, just like all the other (Latin alphabet) letters. How do I do this? I use `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` as my font.

Comment: This is a style decision; some typographic tradition, for instance in France, want capital Greek in italics, others (British and American) want them upright.

Comment: @egreg isn't it rather that the French want their lowercase Greek upright?

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119248/why-latex-uses-upright-uppercase-greek-letters-by-default-in-math-mode?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the manual of `mathdesign`,

```
\usepackage[charter,greekuppercase=italicized]{mathdesign}
```

should do.

However, how the uppercase Greek letters should appear is a style decision and there's not a *correct* way. It mostly depends on the typographic tradition you're following.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Regarding “correct“: I have the Python way of thinking: There should be one obvious way to do things. So I want people to read my stuff and immediately know what I meant. Since all latin and lowercase greek letters are in italic, it makes no sense to me that uppercase should not be in italic as well. And I can use `\mathrm \Delta` as a Laplace operator now, since `\Delta` looks different this way.

Comment: The italic shape of Latin letters is also a style decision and not an 'obvious' way of doing things. It is 'obvious' only to people who never thought they could do otherwise!

Comment: Okay, then I'd have to look at it a little more flexibly. But I still think that it is more *consistent* (not *right*, granted), to have uppercase italic by default.