# How do I make greek uppercase latters upright/roman again?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, greek, capitalization

For some reason, when I last compiled my TEX code, all uppercase greek letters are suddenly no longer [upright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119248/82853). Unfortunately, I don't remember what exactly I changed. I found that the package `upgreek` is used, but I think that only creates alternative commands for upright greek letters. Can you give me hints of where to find these settings? The document's setup TEX script is over 1000 lines long and I don't even know where to start looking...

Additional info: I am using MiKTeX and PdfLaTeX. I only use the default fonts.

Comment: sorry but you will have to show some code. You don't even say which engine you are using or which fonts.

Comment: If you copied a lot of code from someone else’s template, or even pasted in a bunch of code from multiple templates, it might be a good idea to remove packages one by one until you’re down to what you actually need.  You almost certainly do not really need a thousand-line preamble.